# Listen specific Outlook account with vb

Tags: outlook-addin

I would like to request your help here. I am trying to code a script (Outlook Add-in VSTO) to listen all the incoming emails from an specific Outlook account. In my Outlook application I have set up a few accounts (Exchange accounts) but I am interesting only in one of these. I have the below code which listen the inbox folder from the current default account.

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

   Dim outlookNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   outlookNameSpace = Me.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   inbox = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
   Mailitem = inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) Handles Mailitem.ItemAdd
   If TypeOf (item) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
       --Do some things here--
   End if

End Sub
```

The code run perfect but it is listening the default account. I want to change it to listen another account set up in Outlook.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, find the store you are after in the `Namespace.Stores` collection and retrieve the Inbox folder from that store using `Store.GetDefaultFolder`

Comment: Thank Dmitry! Unfortunately I don´t understand how to use Store.GetDefaultFolder. Would you mind to show me an example?

Comment: My default account in lucas@hotmail.com but the one I am interesting in is lucas2@hotmal.com. Both accounts are set up in Outlook. I need to listen all incoming email from lucas2@hotmail.com

Comment: I am not sure I understand - call Store.GetDefaultFolder just like you do now with the Namespace object. Are you having problems finding the right Store object?

Comment: I got it. I used "getNameSpace.Stores() as you recomended. Now I have a question: With this method I can only listen to one account. It there a way to process all incoming emails from all accounts in Outlook?

Comment: Try to have an array of the Items objects

Answer (score 0):

this may help!!!
copy this code in outlook  session.
[outlook session image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJm9F.png)

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session

  Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("your other email address name\Inbox").Items
  Set objNS = Nothing

  Set objInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set objItems = objInbox.Items

  End Sub

  Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error Resume Next
  'your code what you want to do  with additional email address
  End Sub

  Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  'your code for your default email address
  End Sub

  Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

    GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```